# How to make a vertically growing div push the elements above it upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a chat with dynamic content, the sizes of the images on each div are variable in size and once loaded in tend to push the elements below it down.

I thought a good solution to this problem would be to have the div expand in size upwards so it pushes the elements above it upwards so at least the layout shift happens mostly above the viewport.

I have tried making a flexbox with `flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-end`, it works initially but once I get to the top it doesn't make the div overflow (scroll) with `overflow:scroll`.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

codepen here https://codepen.io/BitRain/pen/MWGxzXN

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve, the items above get pushed up and cause the div to `overflow: scroll` and continue to be pushed upwards. This is just `display: block` and the whole container rotated 180deg

[image]

Comment: use `<section>` instead of `<div>` and style it with CSS `flex` or flexbox. Fix the height of the section. Use `flex-direction: column;`.